# How to make a diverse room switcher based on previous rooms?

Tags: java, methods

OK so I'm making a room  switcher, which re-sorts students into 6 rooms - 3 guy rooms and 3 girl rooms. There are 18 guys and 20 girls, and each room holds 6 students, except for two girl rooms which hold 7.

So I figured out long ago how to make it sort randomly people into rooms. And I figured out how to sort guys into their rooms in a diverse way - so that each guy would only be with 1 other guy (the minimum) that was in his previous room. Where I'm really struggling is with the girls. So I want the rooms to be diverse as possible, that means I want the girl rooms to be: 2,2,2; 2,2,3; 2,2,3 (each number representing 2/3 girls who were previously in a room together in the last semester). This part I've been really struggling with. I've been literally struggling with it all day, trying so many different ways to achieve this, and each way failing differently.

So now I'm asking for help. I'm posting here the guys diverse sorter code, and would really appreciate if anyone here could help me adapt it into a working girls diverse sorter code - bearing in mind I already tried to do it a dozen different ways.

```
protected static Person[] Guys = new Person[]{
    new Person("Guy0", 'M', 6),
    new Person("Guy1", 'M', 6),
    new Person("Guy2", 'M', 5),6
    new Person("Guy3", 'M', 4),
    new Person("Guy4", 'M', 6),
    new Person("Guy5", 'M', 5),
    new Person("Guy6", 'M', 6),
    new Person("Guy7", 'M', 4),
    new Person("Guy8", 'M', 4),
    new Person("Guy9", 'M', 5),
    new Person("Guy10", 'M', 5),
    new Person("Guy11", 'M', 5),
    new Person("Guy12", 'M', 4),
    new Person("Guy13", 'M', 4),
    new Person("Guy14", 'M', 6),
    new Person("Guy15", 'M', 5),
    new Person("Guy16", 'M', 4),
    new Person("Guy17", 'M', 6)};

public static void GuysDiverse() {
    resetGuyRooms();
    Randomize(Guys);
    for (int srtM = 0; srtM < Guys.length; srtM++) {
        done = false;
        Person newMove = Guys[srtM];
        {
            while (!done) {
                newMove.rndRoom(); //sets random number from 4 to 6
                switch (newMove.getPrevRoom()) {
                    case 1:
                    case 4:
                        if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 4 && !room4.isFull() && room4.getFromRoom1or4() < 2) {
                            room4.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 5 && !room5.isFull() && room5.getFromRoom1or4() < 2) {
                            room5.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 6 && !room6.isFull() && room6.getFromRoom1or4() < 2) {
                            room6.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                    case 5:
                        if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 4 && !room4.isFull() && room4.getFromRoom2or5() < 2) {
                            room4.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 5 && !room5.isFull() && room5.getFromRoom2or5() < 2) {
                            room5.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 6 && !room6.isFull() && room6.getFromRoom2or5() < 2) {
                            room6.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                    case 6:
                        if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 4 && !room4.isFull() && room4.getFromRoom3or6() < 2) {
                            room4.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 5 && !room5.isFull() && room5.getFromRoom3or6() < 2) {
                            room5.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 6 && !room6.isFull() && room6.getFromRoom3or6() < 2) {
                            room6.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The solution I used which finally worked perfectly was to split the girls into 3 separate arrays.
Below is the code for those interested, it might look a little complex but I assure you it is much simpler than all the other weird solutions I attempted before when I was working with one random array. Indeed this was the simple solution I've been looking for.

```
public static void GirlsDiverse() {
    resetGirlRooms();
    Randomize(Girls);
    for (int srtF1 = 0; srtF1 < room1Arr.length; srtF1++) {
        done = false;
        newMove = room1Arr[srtF1];
        //if()
        {
            while (!done) {
                newMove.rndRoom(); //sets random number from 1 to 3
                if (newMove.getPrevRoom() == 1) {
                    {
                        if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 1 && !room1.isFull() && room1.getFromRoom1or4() < 2) {
                            room1.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 2 && !room2.isFull() && room2.getFromRoom1or4() < 2) {
                            room2.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 3 && !room3.isFull() && room3.getFromRoom1or4() < 2) {
                            room3.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int srtF2 = 0; srtF2 < room2Arr.length - 1; srtF2++) {
        done = false;
        newMove = room2Arr[srtF2];
        //if()
        {
            while (!done) {
                newMove.rndRoom(); //sets random number from 1 to 3
                if (newMove.getPrevRoom() == 2) {
                    {
                        if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 1 && !room1.isFull() && room1.getFromRoom2or5() < 2) {
                            room1.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 2 && !room2.isFull() && room2.getFromRoom2or5() < 2) {
                            room2.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 3 && !room3.isFull() && room3.getFromRoom2or5() < 2) {
                            room3.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int srtF3 = 0; srtF3 < room3Arr.length - 1; srtF3++) {
        done = false;
        newMove = room3Arr[srtF3];
        //if()
        {
            while (!done) {
                newMove.rndRoom(); //sets random number from 1 to 3
                if (newMove.getPrevRoom() == 3) {
                    {
                        if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 1 && !room1.isFull() && room1.getFromRoom3or6() < 2) {
                            room1.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 2 && !room2.isFull() && room2.getFromRoom3or6() < 2) {
                            room2.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 3 && !room3.isFull() && room3.getFromRoom3or6() < 2) {
                            room3.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int srtF2b = room2Arr.length-1; srtF2b < room2Arr.length; srtF2b++) {
        done = false;
        newMove = room2Arr[srtF2b];
        //if()
        {
            while (!done) {
                newMove.rndRoom(); //sets random number from 1 to 3
                if (newMove.getPrevRoom() == 2) {
                    {
                        if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 1 && !room1.isFull() && room1.getFromRoom2or5() < 3) {
                            room1.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 2 && !room2.isFull() && room2.getFromRoom2or5() < 3) {
                            room2.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 3 && !room3.isFull() && room3.getFromRoom2or5() < 3) {
                            room3.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int srtF3b = room3Arr.length - 1; srtF3b < room3Arr.length; srtF3b++) {
        done = false;
        newMove = room3Arr[srtF3b];
        //if()
        {
            while (!done) {
                newMove.rndRoom(); //sets random number from 1 to 3
                if (newMove.getPrevRoom() == 3) {
                    {
                        if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 1 && !room1.isFull() && room1.getFromRoom3or6() < 3) {
                            room1.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 2 && !room2.isFull() && room2.getFromRoom3or6() < 3) {
                            room2.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        } else if (newMove.getCurRoom() == 3 && !room3.isFull() && room3.getFromRoom3or6() < 3) {
                            room3.add(newMove);
                            done = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    room1.shuffleRoom();
    room2.shuffleRoom();
    room3.shuffleRoom();
}
```